# blackberry-nativepackager cannot be found on the path when i build for blackberry in ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, blackberry

I have success full add platform in my ionic application as `ionic add platform blackberry10`. after that when i am trying to build for blackberry10 platform then it's giving me and error as `blackberry-nativepackager cannot be found on the path. Aborting.`
Error :- `cmd: Command Failed with exit code 1`

Is there any solution for this to solve this problem so that i can continue my development with ionic framework.

If any one wants some extra information other then this then please let me know

Thank you Guys in Advanced